# What are the differences between Zie, Sie, Ey, Ve, Tey, E

Tags: gender, language

Stack Exchange have released a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) about changing their policy and CoC on using personal pronouns. I am not familiar with all of the personal pronouns linked in an article that they cite on the linked meta post.

What exactly are the definitions of each of these personal pronouns, and their differences?

`Zie, Sie, Ey, Ve, Tey, E`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to achieving an interpersonal goal. Questions here are related to interpersonal skills.

Comment: @ElizB where would be a better place to post this on SE?

Comment: I honestly don't know. My scope is only within this site and part of Meta Stack Exchange. It may be better for you to do research on this and ask people who use these pronouns or know someone who does?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about interpersonal skills, but rather definitions of words. I haven't read the link they came from, is there not an explanation on that site? Otherwise you might search one of the stacks on English (English Language and Usage or English Language Learners - I'm pretty sure I've seen questions on neopronouns there before, but I'm on mobile right now and can't search easily)

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation See these sites, and when you tap on a banner, you'd see a brief description too. For details, individual tours are always there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pronouns you listed `Zie, Sie, Ey, Ve, Tey, E` are all **gender neutral** pronouns.

Their meanings are mostly subjective to those who self-identify with them.

The key similarity is the gender neutral-ness of them. They are used in place of `he/him` and `she/her`, because those who self-identify with these alternative pronouns use them to specify that they do not fall within binary gender categories (he/him, she/her).

Further than that, the choice of pronoun is simply a personal preference. https://www.mypronouns.org mentions them all, but describes each of them simply as gender-neutral, rather than a set of distinct gender identities.

Comment: No feedback from the downvoter?

Comment: Most likely because you're answering an off topic question which is discouraged.